# RecyclerView don't clip item in the corner

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I want to make recyclerView round corner but seem like if the child item has background color, it will cover to the recyclerView and couldn't be clipped. Here is the design
If I remove the background color of item, then it could be like my design. But unfortunately, sometime it has blue background

[image: Design]

Here is what my app show
[image: Here is what my app show]

Here is my item layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/item_popover"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/dp_8"
    android:background="@color/white"
    tools:ignore="RtlHardcoded,RtlSymmetry"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <com.jp.base.customView.AppImageView
        android:id="@+id/img_notification"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/dp_8"
        app:srcCompat="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/dp_8"
        android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/dp_8"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView
        android:id="@+id/img_arrow"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_keyboard_arrow_right_blue_24dp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <com.jp.base.customView.AppTextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_message"
        tools:text="Message....\nMessage"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/img_notification"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/img_arrow"
        android:maxLines="5"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/dp_5"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <com.jp.base.customView.AppTextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_time"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/dp_8"
        android:drawablePadding="@dimen/dp_8"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:textSize="@dimen/text_small"
        app:app_leftDrawable="@drawable/ic_access_time_black_24dp"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/img_arrow"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/img_notification"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tv_message"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="100"
        tools:text="a month ago" />

    <View
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/tv_time"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/dp_8"
        android:background="@color/gray"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0.5dp" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

My RecyclerView:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/list_notification"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="-30dp"
            android:background="@drawable/rect_bound_bottom_5dp"
            android:clipChildren="true"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/tv_popup_title"
            tools:listitem="@layout/item_popover" />
```

Answer (score 3):

I would try:

- Setting "round rect" Outline on the Recycler View - setOutline
- This is usually used to provide a shadow effect together with "elevation" but if you don't need a shadow - you can skip the elevation part
- Finally call setClipToOutline again on the RecyclerView

Comment: This works correctly, although min SDK 21 is required.

Answer (score 3):

**Most easy solution will be**

Just wrap your `RecyclerView` inside `CardView`.

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    tools:cardCornerRadius="50dp"
    tools:cardElevation="0dp">

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        ... 
        />
</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

Use `cardCorderRadius` to change corner radius.